# Unknown C String Truncation/Overwrite

Tags: c, memory, truncation

I am having an interesting memory problem with a simple string manipulation. The problem itself isn't actually in the reading of the string but right before it when I am trying to call the string.

```
char *removeInvalid(char *token){
    fprintf(stderr," Before: %s \n", token);
    char *newToken = malloc(sizeof(100) + 1);
    fprintf(stderr," After: %s \n", token);
}
```

Whenever I run this, the string if truncated right after the char *newToken is malloc'd. So the printout of this results in

```
Before: Willy Wanka's Chochlate Factory
After: Will Wanka's Chochlate F!
```

Anyone have any clue what this is? I looked at other examples of malloc, but can't figure out how it is going wrong here.

EDIT: FULL CODE BELOW. Take note I am a college student who just began C, so it isn't perfect by anymeans. But it works up until this error.

Function calls goes as follows. Main->initialReadAVL (This part works perfectly)
Then after commandReadAVL is called which goes commandReadAVL->ReadHelper (Again works fine here. 
Then CleanUpString->removeSpaces(works fine)
Then CleanUpString->removeInvalid(THIS IS WHERE IT ERRORS)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "node.h"
#include "avl.h"
#include "scanner.h"
#include "bst.h"

/* Options */
int avlSwitch = 0;
int bstSwitch = 0;
int insertSwitch = 0;
int deleteSwitch = 0;
int frequencySwitch = 0;
int displaySwitch = 0;
int statisticSwitch = 0;

int ProcessOptions(int argc, char **argv);
char *cleanUpString(char *token);
char *turnToLowerCase(char *token);
char *removeSpaces(char *token);
char *removeInvalid(char *token);
char *readHelper(FILE *in);
void Fatal(char *fmt, ...);
void preOrder(struct node *root);
void initialReadAVL(avl *mainAVL, FILE *in);
void initialReadBST(bst *mainBST, FILE *in);
void commandReadBST(bst *mainBST, FILE *commandList);
void commandReadAVL(avl *mainAVL, FILE *commandList);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct avl *mainAVL;
    struct bst *mainBST;
    FILE *text;
    FILE *commandList;


    if(argc != 4){
        Fatal("There must be 4 arguments of form 'trees -b corpus commands' \n");
    }

    int argIndex = ProcessOptions(argc,argv);

    text = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    commandList = fopen(argv[3], "r");

    //Protect against an empty file.
    if (text == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"file %s could not be opened for reading\n", argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (commandList == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"file %s could not be opened for reading\n", argv[3]);
        exit(1);
    }


    if (avlSwitch){
        mainAVL = newAVL();
        initialReadAVL(mainAVL, text);
        preOrder(mainAVL->root);
        fprintf(stderr,"\n");
        commandReadAVL(mainAVL, commandList);
        preOrder(mainAVL->root);
        fprintf(stderr,"\n");
    }
    else if (bstSwitch){
        mainBST = newBST();
        initialReadBST(mainBST, text);
        preOrder(mainBST->root);
        commandReadBST(mainBST, commandList);
        preOrder(mainBST->root);
    }


    return 0;
}


void commandReadAVL(avl *mainAVL, FILE *commandList){
    char *command;
    char *textSnip;
    while(!feof(commandList)){
        command = readHelper(commandList);
        textSnip = readHelper(commandList);
        textSnip = cleanUpString(textSnip);

        if(command != NULL){
            switch (command[0]) {
            case 'i':
                fprintf(stderr,"%s \n", textSnip);
                insertAVL(mainAVL, textSnip);
                break;
            case 'd':
                deleteAVL(mainAVL, textSnip);
                break;
            case 'f':
                break;
            case 's':
                break;
            case 'r':
                break;
            default:
                Fatal("option %s not understood\n",command);
            } 
        }

    }
}

void commandReadBST(bst *mainBST, FILE *commandList){
    char *command;
    char *textSnip;
    while(!feof(commandList)){
        command = readHelper(commandList);
        textSnip = readHelper(commandList);
        textSnip = cleanUpString(textSnip);
        if(command != NULL){
            switch (command[0]) {
                case 'i':
                    insertBST(mainBST, textSnip);
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    deleteBST(mainBST, textSnip);
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    break;
                case 's':
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    break;
                default:
                    Fatal("option %s not understood\n",command);
                } 
        }
    }
}


char *readHelper(FILE *in){
    char *token;
    if (stringPending(in)){
        token = readString(in);
    }
    else {
        token = readToken(in);
    }
    return token;
}

void initialReadBST(bst *mainBST, FILE *in){
    char *token;
    while(!feof(in)){

        token = readHelper(in);
        token = cleanUpString(token);
        if (token != NULL){
            insertBST(mainBST, token);
        }
    }
}

void initialReadAVL(avl *mainAVL, FILE *in){
    char *token;
    while(!feof(in)){

        token = readHelper(in);
        token = cleanUpString(token);
        if (token != NULL){
            insertAVL(mainAVL, token);
        }
    }
}

//Helper Function to clean up a string using all the prerequisites. 
char *cleanUpString(char *token){
    char *output = malloc(sizeof(*token)+ 1);
    if (token != NULL){
        output = removeSpaces(token);
         fprintf(stderr,"before : %s \n", output);
        output = removeInvalid(output);
         fprintf(stderr,"%s \n", output);
        output = turnToLowerCase(output);
        return output;
    }
    return NULL;

}

//Helper function to turn the given string into lower case letters
char *turnToLowerCase(char *token){
    char *output = malloc(sizeof(*token) + 1);
    for (int x = 0; x < strlen(token); x++){
            output[x] = tolower(token[x]);
        }
    return output;
}

//Helper function to remove redundent spaces in a string.
char *removeSpaces(char *token){
    char *output;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    while (x < strlen(token)){
        if (token[x]== ' ' && x < strlen(token)){
            while(token[x] == ' '){
                x++;
            }
            output[y] = ' ';
            y++;
            output[y] = token[x];
            y++;
            x++;
        }
        else {
            output[y] = token[x];
            y++;
            x++;
        }

    }
    return output;

}

char *removeInvalid(char *token){
    fprintf(stderr," Before: %s \n", token);
    char *newToken = malloc(sizeof(* token)+ 1);
    fprintf(stderr," After: %s \n", token);


    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    while (x < strlen(token)){
        if (!isalpha(token[x]) && token[x] != ' '){
            x++;
        }
        else {
            newToken[y] = token[x];
            y++;
            x++;
        }
    }
    return newToken;
}


//Processes a system ending error. 
void Fatal(char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;

    fprintf(stderr,"An error occured: ");
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    exit(-1);
    }


//Processes the options needed to be executed from the command line
int ProcessOptions(int argc, char **argv) {
    int argIndex;
    int argUsed;
    int separateArg;

    argIndex = 1;

    while (argIndex < argc && *argv[argIndex] == '-')
        {
        /* check if stdin, represented by "-" is an argument */
        /* if so, the end of options has been reached */
        if (argv[argIndex][1] == '\0') return argIndex;

        separateArg = 0;
        argUsed = 0;

        if (argv[argIndex][2] == '\0')
            {
            separateArg = 1;
            }

        switch (argv[argIndex][1])
            {
            case 'b':
                bstSwitch = 1;
                break;
            case 'a':
                avlSwitch = 1;
                break;
            default:
                Fatal("option %s not understood\n",argv[argIndex]);
            }

        if (separateArg && argUsed)
            ++argIndex;

        ++argIndex;
        }

    return argIndex;
}


void preOrder(struct node *root) {
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"%s ", root->key);
        preOrder(root->lChild);
        preOrder(root->rChild);
    }

}
```

ReadString()

```
char *
readString(FILE *fp)
    {
    int ch,index;
    char *buffer;
    int size = 512;

    /* advance to the double quote */

    skipWhiteSpace(fp);
    if (feof(fp)) return 0;

    ch = fgetc(fp);
    if (ch == EOF) return 0;

    /* allocate the buffer */

    buffer = allocateMsg(size,"readString");

    if (ch != '\"')
        {
        fprintf(stderr,"SCAN ERROR: attempt to read a string failed\n");
        fprintf(stderr,"first character was <%c>\n",ch);
        exit(4);
        }

    /* toss the double quote, skip to the next character */

    ch = fgetc(fp);

    /* initialize the buffer index */

    index = 0;

    /* collect characters until the closing double quote */

    while (ch != '\"')
        {
        if (ch == EOF)
            {
            fprintf(stderr,"SCAN ERROR: attempt to read a string failed\n");
            fprintf(stderr,"no closing double quote\n");
            exit(6);
            }
        if (index > size - 2) 
            {
            ++size;
            buffer = reallocateMsg(buffer,size,"readString");
            }

        if (ch == '\\')
            {
            ch = fgetc(fp);
            if (ch == EOF)
                {
                fprintf(stderr,"SCAN ERROR: attempt to read a string failed\n");
                fprintf(stderr,"escaped character missing\n");
                exit(6);
                }
            buffer[index] = convertEscapedChar(ch);
            }
        else
            buffer[index] = ch;
        ++index;
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        }

    buffer[index] = '\0';

    return buffer;
    }
```

INPUT: Commands.txt

```
i "Willy Wonka's Chochlate Factory"
```

INPUT testFile.txt

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the calling code?

Comment: You know that `sizeof(100) + 1` is one more than the size of `int`, right?  Likely 5 or so...

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks, sadly however that didn't fix the error.

Comment: Why do you assign one more byte than is needed for a pointer to a character, store that value in `command`, and then throw it away by assigning something else to `command`? Bluntly, a lot of this code makes no sense and it's not at all surprising that it fails in strange ways.

Comment: That was in trying to fix this problem. I reverted that back as well as many others to just a variable assignment. I agree that makes no sense, but I wanted to see if preallocated it helped at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *turnToLowerCase(char *token){
    char *output = malloc(sizeof(*token) + 1);
    for (int x = 0; x < strlen(token); x++){
            output[x] = tolower(token[x]);
        }
    return output;
}
```

This is probably your main issue. You allocate enough space for two characters and then proceed to store lots more than that. You probably wanted:

```
    char *output = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
```

Since `token` is a `char*`, `*token` is a `char`. So `sizeof(*token)` is `sizeof(char)` -- definitely not what you want.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. I just experimented with this, switching around my function calls of removeInvalid and removeSpaces. The error then disappeared in removeinvalid, and reappeared in removeSpaces. What would be the best way to accomplish the declaration of the char *output so that it is the size of token? Would removing the pointer work?

Comment: You need one byte for each character in the input string plus one byte for the terminate zero byte. Hence `strlen(token)+1`.

Comment: But please, do not expect code to work at all, ever, if you include things you don't understand. If you're trying to make sense of code, remove any such things first. It's not productive and is actually harmful to understanding -- even if it works, you don't even understand what you changed. And if it works by accident (because it moves the problem elsewhere), you will actively add misunderstandings.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I didn't see you actually put the answer in your post. Some how my eyes glanced over it. I have made that change and my program is indeed working. I heed your warning well however. I understand that if I don't understand then I will never learn, and hence will never get better, cascading problems throughout my code. I am going to write a response to my one question. Let me know if I am accurate in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly have a buffer overrun in some part of the code that you're not showing us. If I were to guess, I'd say you allocate too little storage for `token` to contain the full string you're writing into it in the first place.

Did you by any chance allocate `token` using the same erroneous code you have in `removeInvalid()`:

```
malloc(sizeof(100) + 1);
       ^^^^^^^^^^^ this doesn't allocate 101 characters, it allocates sizeof(int)+1
```

Comment: Thanks. So it is in another part of the code then. Do you know any techniques to quickly find a memory overflow like that? Or do I just need to go check every malloc call? I'll start looking into the token call right now.

Comment: You could use valgrind (http://valgrind.org/), though I suspect that the issue is that you're using something similar to `sizeof(100)` in other parts of your code. This allocates much less than 100 bytes.

Comment: I have since done that. Scanning through my code again. I have added readString if you want to look at that. I doubt it has any erroneous code however, as it is a module created by my professor.

Comment: Above comment was supposed to go below David's post.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *readHelper(FILE *in){
    char * token = malloc(sizeof(char *) + 1);
    if (stringPending(in)){
        token = readString(in);
    }
    else {
        token = readToken(in);
    }
    return token;
}
```

It's hard to make sense of this without being able to see `readString` or `readToken`, but this can't possibly be right.

First, you allocate one more byte than is needed for a pointer to one or more characters. What use would such a thing be? If you're not storing a pointer to one or more characters, why use `sizeof(char *)`? If you are storing a pointer to one or more characters, why add one? It's hard to imagine the reasoning that lead to that line of code.

Then, in the `if`, you immediately lose the value you got back from `malloc` because you overwrite `token` by using it to store something else. If you weren't going to use the value you assigned to `token`, why did you assign it at all?

Bluntly, a lot of this code simply doesn't make any sense. Without comments, it's hard to understand the reasoning so we could point out what's wrong with it.

Either there was reasoning behind that line of code, in which case it's just completely wrong reasoning. Or worse, the line of code was added with no reasoning in the hopes it would work somehow. Neither method will produce working code.

When you're trying to debug code, first remove anything you added experimentally or that you didn't understand. If you do understand `malloc(sizeof(char *) + 1)`, then please explain what you think it does so that your understanding can be corrected.

Why did you think you needed a buffer that was one byte larger than the size of a pointer to one or more characters?

Comment: The reasoning to that line of code was trying to allocate it to a size of char* for which I declared the variable. Then adding 1 for a null pointer at the end. I see now that that is erronious and have removed it. I did it in an experiment to fix the code. I edited the code to remove such erronous code and readded it into the OP.

Comment: @KurtAnderson Again, it is absolutely *vital* that you remove any code that was experimental or that you don't understand. Failing to do that makes debugging impossible.

Comment: Two other things: 1) C-style strings are terminated with a single zero byte, not a null pointer (which is typically more than one byte). 2) That zero byte would terminate the characters and would follow *them* in memory, not any pointer.

Comment: And you still have this same problem in `cleanUpString`. Look at `output`.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of David Schwartz and the other posters I was able to find the bug in my problem. When I was allocating memory for my token/output, I wasn't allocating enough space.. Using the erroneous code of

```
malloc(sizeof(100) + 1);
```

and

```
malloc(sizeof(*token) + 1);
```

both of which produced only a couple of bytes to be allocated. This caused a buffer problem causing random letters and numbers/ truncation to happen. The first resulting in the space equivalent to int + 1 and the second in char + 1. (as I was taking the sizeof *token which is just the size of what it originally started as, a char*)

To fix this I changed the allocation of my token variable to that of

```
malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
```

This allocates a space equivalent to the "string" length of token + 1. Allowing the appropriate space for my problem which would end up with space of <= token.

Comment: By the way, you have *lots* more problems. You just fixed the one that was causing your code to crash. One main problem is that you never consider the lifetime of the objects you allocate and so have no ability to free them when you are done with them.

Comment: Yah I know. Like I said in the original post, this is a college assignment, only meant to teach the use of an AVL tree. We are specficially told not to worry about memory/object management or freeing at this point, as that will come in later lessons. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: That's unfortunate. They are essentially forcing you to learn bad habits. People frequently go back to whatever they learned first, and you only have one chance to learn something for the first time. This is a terrible way to teach people C. They are *forcing* you to use concepts you don't understand and *telling* you not to understand them. How are you supposed to learn like that?